# How does Spring boot work with static content?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have simple AngularJS single page application and Spring Boot for back end. I need to return `index.html` on different URLs. I created this kind of controller:

```
@Controller
public class WebResourcesController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sample")
    public String sample() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

but request to ***`localhost:8080/sample`*** returns status **404**. When I changed controller to `return "index.html";` I get proper html file and page loads. I couldn't understand how does spring boot work with static content can anybody explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serve a view within a controller, you have to make sure that the **index.html** page is within the **src/main/resources/templates** folder and not within  the public or static folder (to serve static HTML pages).

Now you can make a controller with a mapping like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
public String sample() {
    return "index";
}
```

Just make sure that you have **spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf** on your classpath. This will make sure that your view is parsed correctly by a view engine (Thymeleaf in this case).

By default Thymeleaf runs in **HTML5** mode, so that should be no issue, however, it expects tags to be properly closed as well. If you want to have more freedom (eg., people often don't close `<meta>` tags) you should add the **nekohtml** dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
    <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You should also configure the `spring.thymeleaf.mode`:

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

If you do all this, you can go to any path and it will show you the index.html page. This is something you usually want if you write Single Page Applications (SPA) and you don't want to use hash location routing (`#`).

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) **Spring Boot** article, you can see if your content is placed in any of the mentioned(in article) directory structure, it will be loaded automatically. But as you said `index` gives holy **`404`** because;

It is expecting it to be dealt by some `ViewResolver`, because it is just a **`String`** and it needs a resolver to tell the Spring Container that whenever a resource is loaded from specific directory structure it should deal it as a View page and render it on browser.

Coding example:

**Java Based:**

```
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
}
```

inside a Config class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and is annotated with `@Configuration` so it tells Spring Container to handle that String view name.

**XML Config:**

```
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
          <property name="prefix" value ="/WEB-INF/views/" />
          <property name="suffix" value =".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Hope, it is clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply set below properties in application.properties

```
#spring.mvc.view.prefix=/html //folder where html files resides
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```